# Rails: DRYing similar but different views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view

I have a pair of very similar views that render almost identical information, only in one view there are couple of extra columns and in the other the rows link slightly different nested resources. My initial approach was to keep it DRY by using a partial and then placing conditionals throughout the view. The resulting partial looked something like this:

```
<div id='overview_table'>
  <div id="overview_header">
    <span id="sort_title" class="title cell">Title<span id="publication_sort_arrow"> &darr;</span></span>
    <span id="sort_author" class="author cell">Author</span>
    <span id="sort_status" class="status cell">Status</span>
    <% if @user.present? %>
        <span id="sort_impression_date" class="date cell">Date</span>
        <span id="sort_impression_vote" class="votes cell">Votes</span>
        <span id="sort_children_total" class="children_total cell">Replies</span>
    <% end %>
  </div>
  <span id="sort_method">title ASC</span>
  <% @publications.each do |publication| %>
    <div class='<%= cycle("odd", "even") %>'>
        <% if @user.present? %>
            <% link = [@user, publication] %>
        <% else %>
          <% link = [@group, publication] %>
        <% end %>
        <%= link_to(link, :remote => true) do %>
            <span class="title cell"><%= publication.full_title %></span>
            <span class="author cell"><%= publication.authors %></span>
            <span class="status cell"><%= publication_status(publication.status) %></span>
            <% if @user.present? %>
                <span class="date cell"><% if publication.impression_date %><%= publication.impression_date.strftime("%B %d, %Y") %><% end %></span>
                <span class="votes cell"><% if publication.impression_vote %><%= publication.impression_vote.to_i %><% end %></span>
                <span class="children_total cell"><% if publication.impression_vote %><%= publication.children_total %><% end %></span>
            <% end %>
        <% end %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

It worked fine, but the code felt hacky. I ultimately separated these back out into the two different views, though now there's a lot of repeated code. Both approaches feel inadequate. Is there another approach that I'm not considering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different strategies here but in this case if you are just adding some fields, I would do something like this (which is similar to what you are doing).

in my controller I'll set some tag value to true:

```
@show_val_extra=true
```

and in my view(probably be a partial so rather than inline code in your example):

```
  <%="something here" unless @show_val_extra.nil? %>
```

No matter what you are going to have to check and other issues of managing the view in the controller are ugly to me. YMMV but this is what I'd do since it basically makes it to a single value and a single check for when you want different information. Usually, it's in multiple places but you have content in multiple places and a further refactor is easy if the situation arises.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Guess I shouldn't be surprised that there isn't some magic approach to this, but I had to make sure.