# Slightly different content many Rails views - how to be DRY

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Hopefully I haven't duplicated a question.  It's similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8552763/best-way-to-highlight-current-page-in-rails-3-apply-a-css-class-to-links-con) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14279258/rails-drying-similiar-but-different-views) but not quite.

On the subject of duplication, this is my problem.  I'm new to Rails btw.

I have a (Twitter Bootstrap) set of pills/tabs and I want the `<li>` class to be set to `"active"` if the user is on the page associated with that tab.  So far I'm doing it a stupid way.. in each of my views I have this (simplified):

```
<% content_for :pills do %>
  <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
  <li class="active"><a href="/about">About</a></li> <----------- active class
  <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
<% end %>
```

and in each view I have the same code (doh) but with the class set to `"active"` on another tab/pill.

Most tab content comes from the same `app/views/<some view directory>/` but one tab comes from `app/views/<some OTHER view directory>/` but I guess this isn't a problem.

How do I solve this without repeating similar code in each view?

Many thanks.

Comment: maybe creating some partials would help?  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

Answer (score 1):

I've actually run into the same thing and created a helper that I've used in a few projects.

Add this to an `app/helpers/layout_helper.rb` file.

```
module LayoutHelper
  def nav_class_for(*controllers)
    :active if controllers.any? do |controller|
      controller_name.to_sym == controller.to_sym || params["#{controller.to_s.singularize}_id"]
    end
  end
end
```

Then I use it like this.

```
<li class="<%= nav_class_for(:about) %>"><a href="/about">About</a></li>
```

Just pass it the name of the controller or controllers that you want the menu item to be active for. It should also be active for any nested routes beneath those controllers.

Comment: so nearly what I need :).. I just need the LayoutHelper to look at the action name too because I have multiple views for the same controller.  Any ideas?  I'll keep trying and post a comment if I solve it.